# Looping through hour value in Unix

Tags: shell, unix

I have date variable with format yyyymmddhh. I am trying to loop through the hour element in it. I tried below way but it's failing to produce output.

```
now=2018100600
end=2018100804
while [ "$now" != "$end" ] ;
do
        now=`date +"%Y%m%d%H" -d "$now + 1 hour"`;
        echo $now
done
```

Output expected from above script is 2018100601,2018100602,...2018100804

I am getting error as date: `invalid date ‘-53382311010101 + 1 hour'`.

What can I try next?

Comment: this looks like pure shell question not sure why `awk` is added here.

Comment: Hi. While I was exploring on this I saw gawk scripts handling similar kind of problem. So I though this problem may be solved using awk script also. So only tagged. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it's the best to give GNU date only dates in format `YYYY-mm-dd HH-MM-SS`. He keeps on misinterpreting the input date format. In case you have an openbsd date version (which I like), you can specify the input string fields.

This works:

```
now=2018100600
end=2018100604
while (( now < end )); do
        now=$(
            date --date="${now:0:4}-${now:4:2}-${now:6:2} ${now:8:2}:00:00 +hour" +%Y%02m%02d%02H
        )
        echo "$now"
done
```

but I still feel like using timestamps is safer:

```
now_timestamp=$(date --date="${now:0:4}-${now:4:2}-${now:6:2} ${now:8:2}:00:00" +%s)
end_timestamp=$(date --date="${end:0:4}-${end:4:2}-${end:6:2} ${end:8:2}:00:00" +%s)
for ((i = now_timestamp; i < end_timestamp; i += 60 * 60)); do
    now=$(date --date="@$i" +%Y%02m%02d%02H)
    echo "$now"
done
```

Live example available at [tutorialpoint](http://tpcg.io/ODT8GP).

Answer (score 1):

It works if you swap the `+` and the `-d`: `date -d '2018100602 + 1 hour' '+%Y%m%d%H'`, plus it thinks `2018100600` is not a valid date. But this works, strangely:

```
now='20181006 00'
end='20181008 04'
until [[ $now == $end ]]; do
    now=$(date -d "${now} + 1 hour" '+%Y%m%d %H');
    echo $now
done
```

Comment: Thanks. Its working But when tried with variable replacement its raising error: now=2018100600
date -d '$now + 1 hour' '+%Y%m%d%H'
date: invalid date ‘$now + 1 hour’. Could you please help?

Comment: I updated the answer, can you try with the code from there?

Comment: Hi. Now its working manually : now=2018100800
now=$(date -d "${now%00} + 1 hour" '+%Y%m%d%H');
echo $now
2018100801. But when executed the script its giving error as : 2018100806
201810080601
20181008060101
2018100806010101
-53382311010101
date: invalid date ‘-53382311010101 + 1 hour’.  Could you please help?

Comment: @user2531569 - can you try again (see if adding a space between date and time works for you)

Comment: Yes. With space its working. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @user2531569 - great! you can “accept” this answer then ;-)

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with `date` command a bit, I arrived at a solution below. The date you give with `-d` switch is something `date` doesn't interpret as `yyyymmddhh`, as you'd like it to.

So here's a solution with manual date parsing.

```
#!/bin/sh

now=2018100600
end=2018100604

nowY=$(expr "$now" : "\([[:digit:]]\{4\}\)")
nowM=$(expr "$now" : "[[:digit:]]\{4\}\([[:digit:]]\{2\}\)")
nowD=$(expr "$now" : "[[:digit:]]\{4\}[[:digit:]]\{2\}\([[:digit:]]\{2\}\)")
nowH=$(expr "$now" : "[[:digit:]]\{4\}[[:digit:]]\{2\}[[:digit:]]\{2\}\([[:digit:]]\{2\}\)")

h_counter="$nowH"
((h_counter++))
date_runner=""
while true ; do
    date_runner=$(date -d "$nowY$nowM$nowD + $h_counter hours" +"%Y%m%d%H")
    echo $date_runner
    ((h_counter++))
    [ "$date_runner" == "$end" ] && break
done
```

Though I do think "it's the best to give GNU date only dates in format YYYY-mm-dd HH-MM-SS" advice by @Kamil Cuk is the way to go.